# Swift 3: Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to two 'indexPath' operands

Tags: swift, swift3

The error came from this.  Which was woring fine under Swift 2.3

```
selectedIndexPaths = selectedIndexPaths.filter() { $0 !== indexPath}
```

Where:

```
var selectedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Index path is a struct in swift 3, so you cannot compare the indices as references... Use the **!=** operator, for equality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use `!=`.

It doesn't make sense to compare indices as references.

`IndexPath` is a struct (compared to `NSIndexPath` that is a class type), therefore it's not possible to compare references. However it never made really sense. Just compare them for *equality*.

Comment: So `NSIndexPath` was a reference type in Swift 2, but became a value type in Swift 3? (in addition to being renamed `IndexPath`?)

Comment: @DuncanC No, `NSIndexPath` still exists. `IndexPath` is merely a value-type wrapper for it – see [SE-0069](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md). Although the wording of "*`IndexPath` is now a struct*" should probably lose the "now" ;)

Comment: @DuncanC Swift only imports the Obj-C `NSIndexPath` as a struct `IndexPath`. The same it does for `String` and `NSString`. You can still easily convert one to the other using `as`.  The same is true for many types that were immutable in Obj-C. Also note that table view sometimes reuses `NSIndexPath` to save memory therefore saving and index path from table view and compare the reference was never safe unless you called `copy`.

Comment: @DuncanC: There are two changes in Swift 3 which are sometimes mixed-up: "Overlay types with value semantics" (SE-0069), e.g. IndexPath for NSIndexPath,  and "Dropping the NS Prefix" (SE-0086), e.g. NSBundle is *renamed* to Bundle.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Sulthan said: If you define `selectedIndexPaths` as
a *set*

```
var selectedIndexPaths: Set<IndexPath> = []
```

then you can simply add or remove an index path with

```
selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath)
selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
```

which is simpler and more effective than filtering an array.

Comment: I will switch to Set!